# Does JVM reboot when 100% tenured heap is used

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I've a test system where I see the tenured heap usage increase to 100% and then fall back to ~50%. This keeps happening continuously.

The application is started with following JVM args:

```
-Xms512M -Xmx512M -ea -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/bin/kill -9 %p
```

I don't see any logs that generally appear on application restart.

Comment: *"where I see the tenured heap usage increase to 100%"* is it at 100% before or after a full GC?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you killing the process on `OutOfMemoryError`?  Instead why don't you collect the heap dump file and see why it's full?

```
Use: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/your/preferred/dumplocation
```

and open the resulting dumpfile with Eclipse [MAT](https://eclipse.org/mat/).

Also, I think the option needs to be quoted:

```
"-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p"
```

In reference to your question: No, the process will not restart - it will just terminate when the tenured heap is filled.

Comment: I will do that, but it takes a while before 100% tenured heap is used. Is there another way to debug this?

Comment: You can constrain the heap further by reducing the allotted memory from 512m to something smaller like 256m - but this might obscure the problem further.  I would just be patient and do what I recommended above.

Comment: But my question still holds, if the tenured heap is 100% used, will my process restart with these set of java args?

Comment: JVM will never restart automatically. If yours restart - you must have some script around the caller that does so.

Comment: This is not going to do anything because the OP is not getting an OutOfMemoryError. The GC comes in at 100% usage, and lowers usage to 50%, so no heap dump. Is there a way to dump the heap once the usage gets to around 95%?

Comment: Yes, you can trigger a heap dump on SIGQUIT I believe.